# Building signed Air release build with an ANE gives "unexpected failure: null" error

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

Trying to build a signed release build of my application with an a native extension (ANE file) on Mac. When I build, using either Flash Builder or adt in terminal, I get this error:

```
unexpected failure: null
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.readInt(RandomAccessFile.java:759)
at com.adobe.air.CentralDirectoryReader.readInt(CentralDirectoryReader.java:134)
at com.adobe.air.CentralDirectoryReader.<init>(CentralDirectoryReader.java:55)
at com.adobe.air.ApplicationPackager.addExtensions(ApplicationPackager.java:200)
at com.adobe.air.ApplicationPackager.createPackage(ApplicationPackager.java:68)
at com.adobe.air.nai.NativePackager.createPackage(NativePackager.java:96)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.parseArgsAndGo(ADT.java:571)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.run(ADT.java:419)
at com.adobe.air.ADT.main(ADT.java:469)unexpected failure: null
```

The ANE is the ArduinoConnector (http://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/).

Any Ideas? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with how Flash Builder currently works with ANEs which can make it quite challenging [(see ArduinoConnector FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/as3-arduino-connector/wiki/FAQ) and [this bug on the Adobe Forums)](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4319610#4319610). I have to unzip the ANE (it is a zip file with it's extension changed) and work with it as a folder of files. Zipping the contents of this folder back up and adding the .ane extension works fine when building a normal debug version from Flash builder but this error (the one mentioned in the question above) is thrown when trying to build a release build from a rezipped ANE. Building a release build with my custom ANE that was built with adt, instead of rezipped, works fine.